# Setting up a dynamic report parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a parameter called questions that specifies what questions the user wants to report on.  The number of possible questions is held in another parameter called NumQuestions.  What I want is the drop down for the questions parameter to hold (1,2,3,4,5) when NumQuestions is 5, (1,2,3) when NumQuestions is 3, and so on, but I can't quite find a solution that actually creates the drop down.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

5 January:  I discovered this little wrinkle.  NumQuestions is an internal parameter and I ran into the problem described above.  If I change it to "Visible", everything updates like it should.  But the moment I hide NumQuestions, it stops updating.

Comment: If you google "ssrs cascading parameters" you will find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can create cascading parameters to do this.

Create a single value report parameter(@ReportParam1).

Available Values: select [col] from [table]

Create a multi value report parameter(@ReportParam2) which depends on @ReportParam1.

Available & Default Values: select * from [table] where [col] between 1 and (@ReportParam1)

Comment: I do that.  The problem is that SSRS doesn't update the child parameter when the parent changes.